# Keep failing to select radioButton on Currency SELENIUM JAVA

Tags: java, selenium

My code seems something wrong as sometime it able to select the currency on radiobutton and sometime its not working. Any advise to improve the code by adding timer or something ? Thanks you

HTML :

```
id: enumTable_data
```

CODE :

```
private WebElement getRowForCurrency (String currency)  {
        AbstractPage page = new AbstractPage();
        String[] frame = {"i2ui_shell_content","rcp_content"}; 
        page.switchToFrame(frame);  
        By cell = page.waitUntilPresent(By.xpath("//table[@id='enumTable_data']//nobr[text()[contains(.,'" + currency + "')]]"));
        WebElement currentElement = page.browser().findElement(cell);
        while(!currentElement.getAttribute("tagName").equals("TR")) {
            currentElement = currentElement.findElement(By.xpath(".."));
        }
        return currentElement;
    }

    public void selectCurrency (String currency)    {
        // find the text and get the parent, that is the row that contains the radiolist
        JLog.write("Select Currency: " + currency);
        WebElement row = getRowForCurrency(currency);
        if (row != null)    {
            WebElement radioButton = row.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type='radio']"));
            if (null == radioButton)    {
                JLog.error("Found Document Row, but unable to find document radio button: " + currency, TakeScreenshot.True);
                return;
            }
            radioButton.click();
        } else  {
            JLog.error("Unable to find currency: " + currency, TakeScreenshot.True);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which error/Exception you get when it does not select country?

Comment: the error was saying : Fail to find the element then it die there.

Comment: Can you post the html code for the element or link to the webpage

Answer (score 0):

```
1. you need to wait for the element to be present in the screen 

 public static WebElement findElement(WebDriver driver, By selector, long timeOutInSeconds) {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeOutInSeconds);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(selector));

    return findElement(driver, selector);
  }

  public static WebElement findElement(WebDriver driver, By selector, long timeOutInSeconds, String timeOutMessage) {
    try {
      WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeOutInSeconds);
      wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(selector));

      return findElement(driver, selector);
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
      throw new IllegalStateException(timeOutMessage);
    }
  }

  public static WebElement findElementSafe(WebDriver driver, By selector, long timeOutInSeconds) {
    try {
      return findElement(driver, selector, timeOutInSeconds);
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
      return null;
    }
  }

  public static WebElement findElementSafe(SearchContext context, By selector) {
    try {
      return context.findElement(selector);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      return null;
    }
  }
```